# Hibernate session.flush causing deadlock after modifying entity

Tags: hibernate, transactions

This is the scenario,

```
session.save(entity); //it fires the insert statement
entity.setFirstname("abc");//and modify any parameter
session.flush(); // it fires the update statement
```

Even though the both are in the same session and transaction, why is it getting the following exception

> `session.flush`
>   Lock timeout occurs while waiting RECORD_LOCK of mode EXCLUSIVE(TRANSACTION_ID=3629, UPDATE_TRANSACTION_ID=394821922)